# Samsung S screen turns off while calling

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, calls, screen

during a call, the screen turns off and I become not able to click(touch) any button on the screen. PLEASE help if there is any solution cause it makes me crazy. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is normally face detection that turns the screen off so that you cannot press buttons with your cheek.  If moving the phone away from your face does not turn it on, then you should be able to turn it on with the power button.